# How to add "Click to close" functionality to each <div>?

Tags: jquery

My web app may display messages from time to time. Some of the messages are information:

```
<div class="message">Here is some info.</div>
```

and some of the messages are errors:

```
<div class="error message">jQuery is not your friend.</div>
```

I want users to be able to clear informational messages from the screen, but the errors need to stay, and I thought I could do it by adding a click-to-close feature on each message.

This *sort of* works :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message:not(.error)').each(function() {
    theBox = this;
    $(theBox).css('cursor','pointer')
             .attr('title','Click to close')
             .click( function(){ $(theBox).fadeOut( 1000 ); })
  });
});
```

Sort of. It works fine if there is only one info message on the screen, but if there are two messages only the second one gets hidden, whichever box I click.

Can you please help me tell each `<div>` to close itself when clicked?

Comment: Worth reading: http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html , especially example 5.

Comment: initial problem occured because there is `var` statement missed on `theBox` creation, so it made theBox variable global.

Comment: @Felix Kling: That made my brain hurt :( Have an upvote anyway; I bookmarked it and will keep re-reading until it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use *this* in your click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message:not(.error)').each(function() {
    theBox = this;
    $(theBox).css('cursor','pointer')
             .attr('title','Click to close')
             .click( function(){ $(this).fadeOut( 1000 ); })
  });
});
```

*theBox* is going to refer to the object when the function RUNS (in document ready). As you have it the click event will refer to the LAST VALUE of theBox. You want the current object referred to in the click event. In the scope of the click event it is *this*.

Answer (score 4):

`theBox` changes during the loop. Use `$(this)` instead in your inner callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message:not(.error)').each(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer')
           .attr('title','Click to close')
           .click( function(){ $(this).fadeOut( 1000 ); })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed theBox variable (and just used $(this)) and it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message:not(.error)').each(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer')
             .attr('title','Click to close')
             .click( function(){ $(this).fadeOut( 1000 ); })
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KhCqU/

Comment: I bet addng `var` to `var theBox...` would fix this, too. As is, the scoping is incorrect

Comment: +1 for using jsfiddle which helped me realise why the changes I made weren't having any effect in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I think that changing your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.message:not(.error)').each(function() {
        theBox = this;
        $(theBox).css('cursor','pointer')
            .attr('title','Click to close')
            .click( function(){ $(this).fadeOut( 1000 ); })
    });
});
```

should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

this ought to do it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.message:not(.error)').each(function() {
    theBox = this;
    $(theBox).css('cursor','pointer')
             .attr('title','Click to close')
             .click( function(){ $('.message').fadeOut( 1000 ); })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to close all messages when a message is clicked, using the `.each()` method is bad for optimization and will slow down your code.  Try just using the `event.target` or `this` to determine which element to close instead:

```
var theBox = $('.message:not(.error)');
theBox.css('cursor','pointer')
      .attr('title','Click to close')
      .click(function(e){$(e.target).fadeOut( 1000 );});
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/pL9SV/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want to give the user the option to close on a per-message basis.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  I updated the code and example to incorporate that.  It's still a bad performance hit to use `.each()` so I think this way is better.

Comment: So... have I misunderstood what `.each()` is for?

Comment: `.each()` should be used when you need different functionality for each element.  Here you want the exact same functionality for all of the elements, but if you had wanted to let's say number the messages "Message 1", "Message 2", etc then you would use `.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `theBox` as a global variable. It will work if you use `var theBox` instead to declare a local variable.